# does $ab$ divide $(ab-1)!$?

Tags: number-theory

i am interested in   following  thing, that  for  $a \gt 2$ , $b \gt2$,  $ab$ divides $(ab-1)!$ ?  I can  take  some simple example, for example  $(3,3)$,or $(3,5)$  and  show that this is true  by this way; but  I need  ways to proof it by induction or  by algebra   maybe,how can i do it?
$$(ab-1)! =1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times\cdots\times(ab-1)$$
my logic is that, because  we  are trying to calculate  $(ab-1)!$, then we can find some  pair of numbers, with  by multiply  together will cancel  $ab$, because  each  $a$ and $b$  are less then result of this factorial,this is just a human logic,how to proof it by mathematics logic?

Comment: What you call "just a human logic" is actually perfectly fine "mathematics logic."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $a\leq b$.

First, consider the case where $a<b$. Since $a,b>2$ ,$ab >2a$ and consequently $ab-1 \geq a$. The same argument shows that $ab-1 \geq b$. So, $a$ and $b$ will both occur in the product $(ab-1)!=1\times 2\times3\times \cdots \times a\times \cdots \times b\times (ab-1)$ for all $a,b > 2$.

The case when $a=b$ is much more subtle. Since $a=b$, $(ab-1)!=(a^2-1)!=1\times 2\times3\times \cdots \times a\times \cdots (ab-1)$, so we know that $a$ divides  $(a^2-1)$. We use the hypothesis that $a>2$ to deduce that $a^2>2a. \implies a^2-1 \geq 2a$. So $2a$ is also in the product $1\times 2\times3\times \cdots \times a\times \cdots (ab-1)$. Also note that $a$ is distinct from $2a$ for all non-zero integers. So, use this to summarize that $a^2|(a^2-1)!$.

Comment: The argument is fine if $a\lt b$, but runs into a bit of difficulty if $a=b$, no?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Ja, I just realized that. I will try to fix it.Thanks!

Comment: Does that do it, @ArturoMagidin ?

Comment: if a>b  similar  logic is used  yes?

Comment: @dato. Oh, you dont need to do that case. Just switch the roles of $a$ and $b$ and apply our theorem. This works because $ab=ba$ in the integers.

Comment: thanks  @Fortuon Paendrag  , thanks  very much and good night too

Comment: @FortuonPaendrag: Yes, that would do it.